Error saying unable to find variable with this code .find(what, LookIn, LookAt)

This says error 448: unable to find the variable
Set result = .Range("B:B").Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues, XlLookAt:=xlWhole)
This is working fine but will be finding 11, 12 anything starts with 1 upon .find(next)
Set result = .Range("B:B").Find(1)
Thanks!

Is it a typo? XlLookAt:=xlWhole should be LookAt:=xlWhole. If yes then check leading/trailing spaces at the numbers.

You are the MVP, my bad it was indeed the typo causing the problem, thanks so much!
